# Is there a way to populate a map in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

For example

```
<jsp:useBean id="total" class="java.util.LinkedHashMap"/>
// need somehow do something like this: total.put('key', 'value');
```

But without using scriptlets (it's obvious but a little bit ugly)

Comment: Sorry, I answered before I saw your edit about not using scriptlets. Why can't you just populate the values you need on the server side before using this JSP page?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`<c:set>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/set.html) for this.

```html
<jsp:useBean id="total" class="java.util.LinkedHashMap"/>
<c:set target="${total}" property="key" value="value" />
```

Comment: How do I unit test so I don't have to keep restarting the server each time I want to check how ${total} is resolving.